# Python ONNXRuntime-Directml is using my CPU but I want it to use my AMD GPU

Tags: python, onnxruntime, directml

I am trying to create AI workflows using my Radeon RX 6700 XT on my Windows 10 device.

As of this writing (1/1/24), AMD ROCM framework is not supported on Windows, so I am trying to get Microsoft's DirectML to work instead.

I have installed onnxruntime-directml using pip, but when I print the device used to console, I see it is using "CPU-DML".

How do I force the onnx directml to use my gpu?

Code:

```
import onnxruntime as ort

print(ort.get_device())
```

Comment: My solution was to just buy an NVIDIA gpu. Everything AI is literally plug and play now. Things move fast in the AI world now, but the barriers to entry for non-NVIDIA are still too high for amateurs like myself.